# openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() is slow (PHP)

Tags: php, openssl

I'm using opennssl_random_pseudo_bytes() in PHP and it is performing ultra slowly. My application often timeouts (throws that execution time limit error). Is there a particular reason for OpenSSL random to be this slow? I'm using Windows 7 x86 currently on my developer machine.

Comment: Just by calling it openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8); and it runs very slowly.

Comment: Have you tried it with a longer string, say `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(512)`?

Comment: I don't see any differences between given values whether it's 1, 512 or 1024. The function runs very slowly, always.

Comment: I experience this as well, have no idea why it is so slow...

Comment: I knew other people experience this also, because I have tried the function on four different Windows machines, and the result has always been the same -- the function call is ultra slow. I think it has something to do with Windows and its way of generating entropy in the pool. For some reason OpenSSL gets its entropy very slowly.

Comment: It causes problem to my Windows 2008 server on production, but have no problem on my own computer running Windows XP.
Both machine running PHP 5.3.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was apparently a bug in PHP < 5.3.4.

> Fixed possible blocking behavior in
>   openssl_random_pseudo_bytes on
>   Windows. (Pierre)

http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.4

Comment: It causes problem to my Windows 2008 server on production, but have no problem on my own computer running Windows XP. Both machine running PHP 5.3.1

Comment: @neobie: Since it is stated to have "**possible** blocking behavior", there might be the possibility that it just did not show up on XP, but have you tried it with a version >= 5.3.4 yet?

Answer (score 10):

On Windows, openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() calls OpenSSL's RAND_screen() to generate entropy. It's pretty slow, and PHP is hardly the first unix->windows port that has run up against this. It looks like the common advice is to use RAND_seed() instead.

It's also interesting to note that the OpenSSL documentation states:

> The RAND_screen() function is available for the convenience of Windows programmers. It adds the current contents of the screen to the PRNG.  For applications that can catch Windows events, seeding the PRNG by calling RAND_event() is a significantly better source of randomness. **It should be noted that
>        both methods cannot be used on servers that run without user interaction**.

So this may actually be a certified bug - I've already raised the issue with the core devs. Until a better method for generating entropy for OpenSSL on Win32 becomes available, it appears that the short answer is "Yes, it's slow on Windows. Sorry about that."

Some additional links that discuss the problem:

[Open Bug at rt.openssl.org](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2100&user=guest&pass=guest)
[curl developers discuss alternative methods of collecting entropy on Win32](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2004-06/0133.html)
[Google Groups archive of OpenSSL Users List discussing the slowness of RAND_poll() on Win32](http://groups.google.com/group/mailing.openssl.users/browse_frm/thread/217d4e6e1963cd23?dq&hl=en&lr&ie=UTF-8&prev=/groups?group%3Dmailing.openssl.users&pli=1)
[Another discussion on the slowness of RAND_screen() on mail-archive.com's archive of OpenSSL Users](http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg61551.html)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you run PHP. On my win7-64bit PHP5.3.27

1. Apache + PHP-CGI = It takes 600ms
2. Apache + PHP5 Module = It is instant

Comment: "It is instant" - as a rough benchmark on my Win7-64bit PHP5.5 Module (i7 3.5GHz) I can call `opennssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16)` 1 million times in 1.55(+0.02) seconds. (I had gotten a bit nervous after seeing several, albeit older posts, regarding "slow performance".)