# Gathering entropy in web apps to create (more) secure random numbers

Tags: php, web-applications, cryptography, prng, entropy

after several days of research and discussion i came up with this method to gather entropy from visitors (u can see the history of my research [here](http://www.frostjedi.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=30875))

when a user visits i run this code:

```
$entropy=sha1(microtime().$pepper.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'].
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].serialize($_POST).serialize($_GET).serialize($_COOKIE));
```

note: pepper is a per site/setup random string set by hand.

then i execute the following (My)SQL query:

```
$query="update `crypto` set `value`=sha1(concat(`value`, '$entropy')) where name='entropy'";
```

that means we combine the entropy of the visitor's request with the others' gathered already.

that's all.

then when we want to generate random numbers we combine the gathered entropy with the output:

```
$query="select `value` from `crypto` where `name`='entropy'";
//...
extract(unpack('Nrandom', pack('H*', sha1(mt_rand(0, 0x7FFFFFFF).$entropy.microtime()))));
```

note: the last line is a part of a modified version of the crypt_rand function of the [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).

please tell me your opinion about the scheme and other ideas/info regarding entropy gathering/random number generation.

ps: i know about randomness sources like /dev/urandom.
this system is just an auxiliary system or (when we don't have (access to) these sources) a fallback scheme.

Comment: Is there a specific question?

Comment: This really belongs on codereview because it's asking for an appraisal of a piece of code rather than help addressing a specific problem.

Comment: Rolling your own crypto is usually a bad idea. Randomness sources like /dev/random and /dev/urandom already do this, and do it right, and they're aware of things like how much entropy they have. A fallback scheme can be a bad idea, because it can cover up serious issues with your system.

Comment: From the one of the main properties of Hash-generation algorithms, SHA1 is not revertible. So your code is not add any security in comparison with this: `update `crypto` set `value`=sha1(concat(`value`, DATE())) where name='entropy'"`. This is happen because the SHA1 (designed as) is controvertible.

Comment: DATE() is easy to guess at more so than concat(value, DATE()) is.  Several attacks against PHP's mt_srand() take advantage of this.  PIDs are not a sufficiently random either yet PHP uses them.

Comment: OK, I'm withdrawing my statements and I am starting a bounty instead for giving a wrong answer. Mea Culpa. More information [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2231/cryptographic-security-of-php-mt-rand-function-using-mersenne-twister-algo/2248#2248)

Comment: How did you test the intrinsic methods? How did you test your improvements? What was the result?

Answer (score 11):

**In the best scenario, your biggest danger is a local user disclosure of information exploit. In the worst scenario, the whole world can predict your data.** Any user that has access to the same resources you do: the same log files, the same network devices, the same border gateway, or the same line that runs between you and your remote connections allows them to sniff your traffic by unwinding your random number generator.

How would they do it? Why, basic application of [information theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory) and a bit of [knowledge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) [of](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) [cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine), of course!

You don't have a wrong idea, though! Seeding your PRNG with real sources of randomness is generally quite useful to prevent the above attacks from happening. For example, this same level of attack can be exploited by someone that understands [how `/dev/random` gets populated on a per-system basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) if the system has low entropy or its sources of randomness are reproducible.

If you can sufficiently secure the processes that seed your pool of entropy (for example, by gathering data from multiple sources over secure lines), the likelihood that someone is able to listen in becomes smaller and smaller as you get closer and closer to the desirable cryptographic qualities of a [one-time pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad).

In other words, **don't do this in PHP, using a single source of randomness fed into a single Mersenne twister. Do it properly, by [reading from your best, system-specific alternative to `/dev/random`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550947/how-do-you-generate-cryptographically-secure-random-numbers-with-php), seeding its entropy pool from as many secure, distinct sources of "true" randomness as possible.** I understand you've stated that these sources of randomness are inaccessible, but this notion is strange when similar functions are afforded to all major operating systems. So, I suppose I find the concept of an "auxiliary system" in this context to be dubious.

This will still be vulnerable to an attack by a local user cognizant of your sources of entropy, but securing the machine and increasing the true entropy within `/dev/random` will make it far more difficult for them to do their dirty work short of a [man-in-the-middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

As for cases where `/dev/random` is indeed accessible, you can seed it fairly easily:

- Look at what options exist on your system for using [`/dev/hw_random`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hw_random.txt)
- Embrace [`rngd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/rngd) (or a good alternative) for defining your sources of randomness
- Use [`rng-tools`](http://www.howtoforge.com/helping-the-random-number-generator-to-gain-enough-entropy-with-rng-tools-debian-lenny) for inspecting and improving your randomness profile
- And finally, if you need a good, strong source of randomness, consider investing [in more specialized hardware.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator)

Best of luck in securing your application.

---

PS: You may want to give questions like this a spin at [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com) and [Cryptography.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com) in the future!

Comment: We can assume that /dev/(u)random or openssl are not available, especially since the author has literally wrote it down in the question. Creating a secure random source if those where available would be a deed of futility.

Comment: @owlstead Ah! Excuse my derp. The thing is, there should always be some source of randomness underlying your cryptographic functions. While a better algorithm could be selected (like [Blum Blum Shub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub)), you still have an eavesdropping problem if you rely exclusively on network timings to seed the PRNG. So, I think I'm mostly curious _why_ a source of randomness is inaccessible, even in the auxiliary case, when this is afforded in some form to all major operating systems.

Comment: Well, maybe because the provider of the PHP service does not expose the sources of randomness. The problem is that the random sources that are always available seem to be `random` and `mt_random`, neither of which is secure. Personally I prefer Java on servers, as PHP crypto is severely lacking in many depts. Asker seems to be aware of this and wants to create a (albeit suboptimal) solution to this.

Comment: i am writing a register and login system (plan to release it under GPL). i don't feel the need for extremely secure random numbers, because it's just an ordinary web app run on ordinary (possibly shared) hosting. but i saw mt_rand security too low even for ordinary apps/scenarios. i see no serious problem in falling back to this scheme automatically if more secure sources aren't available. my rand function is a modified version of phpseclib's crypt_rand that will use those better sources automatically if available (and my extra entropy is still combined with their output with sha1).

Comment: @HM Thank you for your clarification! I think, based on your requirements, that I would drop out your Mersenne Twister (see the cryptography note [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister#Applications)) and use a cryptographically superior cypher like, for example, [Blum Blum Shub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub), if and only if you'd like to optimize on strong randomness. In any case you choose, I'd simply document and inform my users about the cryptographic properties of your chosen scheme. I believe this is, given your requirements, the best you can do. :)

Answer (score 4):

### Use Random.Org

If you need truly random numbers, use [random.org](http://www.random.org/). These numbers are generated via **atmospheric noise**. Besides [library for PHP](http://software.onthefive.com/RandDotOrg/), it also has a [http interface](http://www.random.org/clients/http/) which allows you to get truly random numbers by simple requests:

https://www.random.org/integers/?num=10&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new

This means that you can **simply retrieve the real random numbers in PHP** *without* any additional PECL exension on the server.

If you don't like other users to be able to "steal" your random numbers (as MrGomez' argues), just use https with a certificate checking. Here follows an example with https certificate checking:

```
$url = "https://www.random.org/integers/?num=10&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if ($response === FALSE)
        echo "http request failed: " . curl_error($ch);
else
        echo $response;    
curl_close($ch);
```

If you need more information on how to create https requests:

- [Make a HTTPS request through PHP and get response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873187/make-a-https-request-through-php-and-get-response)
- http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

### More on security

Again, some might argue that if the attacker queries random.org at the same time as you, he might get the same numbers and predict.. I don't know if random.org would even work this way, but if you are really concerned, you may lessen the chance by fooling the attacker with dummy request which you throw out, or use only a certain part of the random numbers you get.

As MrGomez notes in his comment, this shall not be considered as an ultimate solution to security, but only as one of possible sources of entropy.

### Performance

Of course, if you need a blitz latency then doing one random.org request per one client request might not be best idea... but what about just doing [one bigger request](https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1000&min=1&max=100&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new) to pre-cache the random numbers like every 5 minutes?

Comment: Good idea! But, [they explicitly inform people not to use it for cryptographic secrecy because of the information leak:](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1628/850) _I should probably note that while fetching the numbers via secure HTTP would protect them from being observed while in transit, anyone genuinely concerned with security should not trust anyone else (including RANDOM.ORG) to generate their cryptographic keys._ -- You can allow yourself to trust them, but you're giving them the keys to every installation of this framework.

Comment: Good note, MrGomez, thanks! However I wouldn't say we are "giving them keys". The question was about *increasing* entropy, so I suppose the random.org would be only used as one of its sources. The attacker would have to possess ALL of these sources. In security there is always a tradeoff between the probablity of break-in and price of the solution. Random.org, while not being the ultimate solution of entropy, is a very cheap source of entropy (see the easy solution above) and by *adding* it, you may only lower the probability of break-in.

Answer (score 1):

To come to the point, as far as i know there is no way to generate entrophy inside a PHP script, sorry for this non-answer. Even if you look at well etablished scripts like [phppass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/), you will see, that their fallback system cannot do some magic.

The question is, whether you should try it anyway or not. Since you want to publish your system under GPL, you propably don't know in what scenario it will be used. In my opinion it's best then to **require a random source, or to fail fast** (die with an appropriate error message), so a developer who wants to use your system, knows immediately, that there is a problem.

To read from the random source, you could call the `mcrypt_create_iv()` function...

```
$randomBinaryString = mcrypt_create_iv($length, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
```

...this function reads from the random pool of the operating system. Since PHP 5.3 it does it on Windows servers as well, so you can leave it to PHP to handle the random source.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to /dev/urandom you can use this:

```
function getRandData($length = 1024) {
    $randf  = fopen('/dev/urandom', 'r');
    $data   = fread($randf, $length);
    fclose($randf);
    return $data;
}
```

UPDATE:
of course you should have some backup in case opening the device fails

Comment: He is asking about the design of the backup function.

Comment: Just a head's up: PHP will buffer 8192 bytes for `fread()` calls whether you need it or not, which can waste a lot of entropy. Use `stream_set_read_buffer($randf, 0);` to disable buffering after the file handle is opened and before `fread()` is called to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2**: **Code Review Warning to Everyone**: Dont use The code in the original question. It's a security liability. If this code is online anywhere **Remove it** as it open the whole system, network and database to a malevolent user. Your not only exposing your code but all of your users data.

**Do not ever Serialize user inputs.** If in your code your already doing it, Stop your server and change your code. This is a great exemple of Not doing crypto by yourself.

**Update 1**: For real security you need to have *UN-guessable* **randomess** in your entropy. A suitable option to add entropy has your Question refer-to is to use the Delta of your *script's execution time* **Not** *microtime() by itself* . Because the Delta  Rely on the load of your server. And so is a combination of the hardware environment, temperature, network load, power load, disk access, Cpu usage and voltage fluctuation which together are unpredictable.

**Using Time(), timestamp or microtime is a flaw in your implementation.**

Script execution Delta Exemple code coming:

@martinstoeckli stated correctly that a Suitable Random generation for crypto is from

```
 mcrypt_create_iv($lengthinbytes, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
```

but is outside the requirements of not having a crypto module

In SQL use the **RAND()** in conjunction with your generated number.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-rand-function.htm

Php offer as well the  **Rand()** function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

they wont give you the same number so you could use both.

Comment: Those are not secure random functions, which was kind of the point.

Comment: @owlstead mt_rand() is just faster then rand() Not more secure.

mt_rand() is less secure then rand() As The distribution of mt_rand() return values biased towards even numbers on 64-bit builds of PHP when max is beyond 2^32.

so crypto wise Rand() suck less then mt_rand().

Comment: @GuruJR - The problem is, that these pseudorandom generators create predictable results. If you start them with the same seed (normally the time), you will get the exact same result. You can think of them as a mathematical function which returns random looking numbers with statistical constraints.

Comment: @martinstoeckli i do know it's the intrinsic problem of all pseudorandom generation from computers.
Even MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM is not pure choas , but at least it try to Normalize it's results. So the seed he need to use need to be a seed that even himself cannot guess , that's why  i propose the Delta of his script's execution time. **Using any timestamp is a flaw in the implementation.**

Comment: @GuruJR - Ok, i think i understand what you mean, you would use two predictable random generators, but they will have two different seeds. My first thought was, that concatenating two unsafe functions will not make a safe function, but then... i'm not expert enough to really judge this. If an attacker would try to precalculate the random values of a set of seeds, he would have to precalculate n^2 values then. Later you added to use the execution time, this may give some real entrophy, though it depends on the script complexity, if the time difference can be measured.

Comment: @martinstoeckli i will do a code that will try to explain the idea. But indeed the constrain of the project makes the security target sub-optimal.

Comment: Using timestamp is not a flaw in the implementation if it is used only as a possible extra entropy and not as one of the sources for providing the minimum entropy required.

Comment: @HM your serializing user inputs **your database is free lunch.**

Answer (score 0):

should you have access to client side, you can enable mouse movement tracking - this is what true crypt is using for extra level of entropy.

Comment: Unless you control the client and the transmission (SSL), I would be pretty wary about relying on anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

as i have said before, my rand function is a modified version of phpseclib's crypt_random function.
u could see it in the link given on my first post. at least the author of the phpseclib cryptographic library confirmed it; not enough for ordinary apps? i don't speak of extreme/theoretical security, just speak about practical security to the extent really needed and at the same time 'easily'/'sufficiently low cost' available for almost all of the ordinary applications on the web.

phpseclib's crypt_random effectively and silently falls back to the mt_rand (which u should know is really weak) in the worst case (no openssl_random_pseudo_bytes or urandom available), but my function uses a much more secure scheme in such cases. it's just a fall back to a scheme that brute-forcing/predicting its output is much harder and (should be) in practice sufficient for all ordinary apps/sites. it uses possible (in practice very likely and hard to predict/circumvent) extra entropy that is gathered over time which quickly becomes almost impossible to know for outsiders. it adds this possible entropy to the mt_rand's output (and also to the output of other sources: urandom, openssl_random_pseudo_bytes, mcrypt_create_iv). if u are informed u should know, this entropy can be added but not subtracted. in the (almost surely really rare) worst case, that extra entropy would be 0 or some too tiny amount. in the mediocre case, which i think is almost all of the cases, it would be even more than practically necessary, i think. (i have had vast cryptography studies, so when i say i think, it is based on a much more informed and scientific analysis than ordinary programmers).

see the full code of my modified crypt_random:

```
function crypt_random($min = 0, $max = 0x7FFFFFFF)
{
    if ($min == $max) {
        return $min;
    }

    global $entropy;

    if (function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
        // openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() is slow on windows per the following:
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940168/openssl-random-pseudo-bytes-is-slow-php
        if ((PHP_OS & "\xDF\xDF\xDF") !== 'WIN') { // PHP_OS & "\xDF\xDF\xDF" == strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)), but a lot faster
            extract(unpack('Nrandom', pack('H*', sha1(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(4).$entropy.microtime()))));
            return abs($random) % ($max - $min) + $min; 
        }
    }

    // see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random
    static $urandom = true;
    if ($urandom === true) {
        // Warning's will be output unles the error suppression operator is used.  Errors such as
        // "open_basedir restriction in effect", "Permission denied", "No such file or directory", etc.
        $urandom = @fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb');
    }
    if (!is_bool($urandom)) {
        extract(unpack('Nrandom', pack('H*', sha1(fread($urandom, 4).$entropy.microtime()))));
        // say $min = 0 and $max = 3.  if we didn't do abs() then we could have stuff like this:
        // -4 % 3 + 0 = -1, even though -1 < $min
        return abs($random) % ($max - $min) + $min;
    }


    if(function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv') and version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '>=')) {
        @$tmp16=mcrypt_create_iv(4, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
        if($tmp16!==false) {
            extract(unpack('Nrandom', pack('H*', sha1($tmp16.$entropy.microtime()))));
            return abs($random) % ($max - $min) + $min;
        }
    }


    /* Prior to PHP 4.2.0, mt_srand() had to be called before mt_rand() could be called.
       Prior to PHP 5.2.6, mt_rand()'s automatic seeding was subpar, as elaborated here:

       http://www.suspekt.org/2008/08/17/mt_srand-and-not-so-random-numbers/

       The seeding routine is pretty much ripped from PHP's own internal GENERATE_SEED() macro:

       http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/tags/php_5_3_2/ext/standard/php_rand.h?view=markup */
    static $seeded;
    if (!isset($seeded) and version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.2.5', '<=')) { 
        $seeded = true;
        mt_srand(fmod(time() * getmypid(), 0x7FFFFFFF) ^ fmod(1000000 * lcg_value(), 0x7FFFFFFF));
    }

    extract(unpack('Nrandom', pack('H*', sha1(mt_rand(0, 0x7FFFFFFF).$entropy.microtime()))));
    return abs($random) % ($max - $min) + $min;

}
```

$entropy contains my extra entropy which comes from all requests parameters' entropy combined till now + current request's parameters entropy + the entropy of a random string (*) set by hand at the installation time.

*: length: 22, composed of lower and uppercase letters + numbers (more than 128 bits of entropy)

Answer (score -1):

rn_rand() should be getting used not rand()

Comment: Please elaborate why this is a solution?

Comment: Improve your answer please.